# IE 11 emulation mode to IE 9 not able to inspect elements

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

To check a UI issue which was reported in IE9 i am using emulation mode in my IE 11.

If i inspect the element in IE 11 with out emulation it works fine but when i change the document mode to 9 and inspect the element it only shows blank

Have any one faced this issue and what is the solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same thing in IE 11 while running an older document mode on a page.  Oddly, the DOM Explorer shows me content for the page, but will not show me the contents of IFrames on that page.

This has never been an issue in IE10 or older, so it's looking a lot like a bug or at least a limitation in IE 11, sadly.

I'm really interested to see if anyone has a workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers [virtual machines](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/) that can be used for testing back to IE 6 under XP.